# aspectJ @AfterReturning not executing

Tags: spring, weblogic, aspectj

following situation:

I'm adding some new methods to an aspect class:

```
public class BulletinLogging extends LoggingServiceImpl {
```

Strange thing is: 'my' methods don't get executed, other methods in the class do get executed.

Searched around on the internet (and this wonderfull site of course as well) but didn't found any solution :(

Maybe you can help?

these are the methods that don't get executed:

```
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* be.fgov.just.cjr.business.bulletin.BulletinService." +
    "findScannedBulletins(..)) && args (parameters)()", returning = "results", argNames = "parameters, results")
    public void logFindScannedBulletins(ExtractRequestParams parameters, ScannedBulletinsResults results) {
        Assert.notNull(parameters);
        Assert.notNull(results);
        Map<LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum, Object> toLogs = new EnumMap<LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum, Object>(LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum.class);
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_RN_NR, parameters.getFilterValues().get(ExtractRequestParams.Fields.nationalNumber.toString()));
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_NUMBER_OF_RESULTS, results.getNumberOfResults());
        log(logMsgCreator.getLogMessage(toLogs), SCANNED_BULLETIN, LIST);
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* be.fgov.just.cjr.business.bulletin.BulletinService." +
    "findScannedBulletin(..)) && args (id)()", returning = "bulletin", argNames = "id, bulletin")
    public void logFindScannedBulletin(Long id, ScannedBulletin bulletin) {
        Assert.notNull(id);
        Assert.notNull(bulletin);
        Map<LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum, Object> toLogs = new EnumMap<LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum, Object>(LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum.class);
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_ID, id);
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_BULLETIN_ID, bulletin.getBulletin().getId());
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_DOS_NR, bulletin.getDossier().getDosNrAsString());
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_PDF_NAME, bulletin.getPdfName());
        log(logMsgCreator.getLogMessage(toLogs), SCANNED_BULLETIN, SEARCH);
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* be.fgov.just.cjr.business.bulletin.BulletinService." +
    "getDossierFromScannedConvictionId(..))", returning = "dossier")
    public void logGetDossierFromScannedConvictionId(JoinPoint joinPoint, Dossier dossier) {
        //Assert.notNull(convictionId);
        Assert.notNull(dossier);
        Map<LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum, Object> toLogs = new EnumMap<LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum, Object>(LoggingElementCriteriaTypeEnum.class);
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_CONVICTION_ID, joinPoint.getArgs()[0]);
        toLogs.put(SCANNED_BULLETIN_DOS_NR, dossier.getDosNrAsString());
        log(logMsgCreator.getLogMessage(toLogs), SCANNED_BULLETIN, SEARCH);
    }
```

these are the methods of

```
public interface BulletinService {

    public ScannedBulletinsResults findScannedBulletins(ExtractRequestParams parameters);

    ScannedBulletin findScannedBulletin(Long id);

    Dossier getDossierFromScannedConvictionId(String convictionId);
```

with following implementation in:

```
@Transactional
public class BulletinServiceImpl implements BulletinService {

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ScannedBulletinsResults findScannedBulletins(ExtractRequestParams parameters) {
        return bulletinDao.findScannedBulletins(parameters, START_DATE);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ScannedBulletin findScannedBulletin(Long id) {
        return scannedBulletinDao.findScannedBulletin(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Dossier getDossierFromScannedConvictionId(String convictionId) {
        return findScannedBulletin(Long.parseLong(convictionId)).getDossier();
    }
```

The code (of BulletinServiceImpl) does gets executed (setting breakpoints and stuff reveals that) and the methods themselves work as expected too (so do tell me the unit tests)

However,

The (aspect) methods don't get executed together with the code where they are aspects from...

any help GREATLY appreciated,

questions/comments for further details as well...

S.

Comment: 2 points: 1) your logger is correctly setup and works right :) ? 2) you define AOP around a Transactional boundary you are realising that right ?

Comment: Hey dimitrisli, the logging should be set up properly (it logs other stuff in the same module) the Transactional point is a really good one, I'll give it a spin tomorrow (I'm at home now and can't run the environment) Thanks a bunch for pointing things out :)

Comment: I've added @Transactional(readOnly = true) to the methods that don't get AOP'ed (see edit) (-> this works in other classes) but this doesn't seem to fix the problem...